# Make cd follow symbolic links

Tags: bash, symlink, cd-command

I have my code mounted as an sshfs in my home directory, but the hierarchy is difficult to remember, so I created a symlink in my home directory leading to that directory. Is there a way so that when I cd to that symbolic link, instead of cding to the symbolic link, it will actually cd to that directory?

If the question was unclear, here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
foo@foo:~$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx  1 foo      foo              5 2012-11-14 08:20 foo -> bar/bar

foo@foo:~$ cd foo
foo@foo:~/bar/bar/$
```

Comment: two [related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36319/symbolic-link-to-a-directory-and-relative-path) [questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/changing-parent-directory-with-symlinks)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

With any POSIX implementation of `cd`, you can use the `-P` option to do this.

```
$ help cd
...
    -P      use the physical directory structure without following symbolic links
...
```

You can see it in action here:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ln -s foo bar
$ cd -P bar
$ pwd
/tmp/tmp.WkupF2Ucuh/foo
```

If you want this to be the default behaviour, you can either create an alias for `cd`, like so:

```
alias cd='cd -P'
```

...or use `set -o physical`. For tcsh, the equivalent command is `set symlinks=chase`.

Comment: And if you don't have a Posix implementation...?

Comment: You do have a POSIX implementation. POSIX is a standard base, somethings are added on top or changed a bit, "With any POSIX implementation" means this will work almost anywhere, i.e. its not something bash or ksh specific.

Comment: zsh note: `set CHASELINKS` is equivalent to `set -o physical` (which I believe is for backward compatibilty with bash).