# Resolving symbolic links (pwd)

Tags: files, symlink, cwd

Say I do the following:

```
cd /some/path
ln -s /target/path symbolic_name
```

If then do:

```
cd /some/path
cd symbolic_name
pwd
```

I get:

```
/some/path/symblic_name
```

and not:

```
/target/path
```

Is there a way to have the shell "fully resolve" a symbolic link (i.e. updating CWD, etc.), as if I had directly done:

```
cd /target/path
```

?

I need to run some programs that seem to be "aware" or "sensitive" about how I get to my target path, and I would like them to think that I arrived to the target path as if had done `cd /target/path` directly.

Comment: Related to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55713/make-cd-follow-symbolic-links). You can do `pwd -P` or `alias pwd='pwd -P'` also `cd -P` to go to the physical path instead of the symlink.

Comment: @MartínCanaval Thanks; that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your shell has a builtin `pwd`, which tries to be "smart". After you did a `cd` to a symlink the internal `pwd` fakes the output as if you moved to a real directory.

Pass the `-P` option to `pwd`, i.e. run `pwd -P`. The `-P` option (for “physical”) tells `pwd` not to do any symbolic link tracking and display the “real” path to the directory.

Alternatively, there should also be a real binary `pwd`, which does not do (and is even not able to do) this kind of magic. Just use that binary explicity:

```
$ type -a pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
pwd is /bin/pwd
$ mkdir a
$ ln -s a b
$ cd b
$ pwd
/home/michas/b
$ /bin/pwd
/home/michas/a
```

Answer (score 20):

Try `cd -P <symlink_dirname>`.

```
tim@ls:~$ mkdir a
tim@ls:~$ ln -s a b

tim@ls:~$ cd b
tim@ls:~/b$ pwd
/home/tim/b

tim@ls:~/b$ cd ..
tim@ls:~$ cd -P b
tim@ls:~/a$ pwd
/home/tim/a
```

You can also use `set -o physical` to make this behavior persist through the lifetime of the running shell.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456784/behavior-of-cd-bash-on-symbolic-links for some more good info.